# git checkout does not find the folders in the new branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I ran 
`git checkout <branch_2>`
to switch from `branch_1` to `branch_2`. Then, run 
`git status` to verify up to date. 
However, a folder existing in `branch_2` still does not show up.

Comment: Git does not track directories at all, only the files in them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "still does not show up". Is it present according to `ls`? `git status` would not mention something unless there were changes to report, are there changes you're expecting to see reported that are not listed?

Comment: I ran `git pull` and see the missing folder in `branch_2`. Guess this is the right way to switch between branches completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I gleaned from the comments, it sounds like when you ran `git checkout`, you expected it to also get all the changes from the remote. This is not the default functionality of `git checkout`. You will have to follow it with a `git pull` to get the changes from remote if you have previously copied the branch to your local machine.

The caveat is that if you've never checked that branch out from remote previously, it will have to go to the remote in order to retrieve the branch, thus giving you the most up-to-date version.

Answer (score 0):

As always, more information is always helpful.

## Standard Answer

I am going to assume that the "folder" you believe should be in `branch_another` was never tracked in the first place.

> At, [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) suggestion, try placing some file inside the desired folder, then commit that to `branch_another`.